# How to select all visible html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jQuery to select all elements, and those elements' recursive children that are not hidden.

Some selections that don't work are the following:

`$("#content").find(":visible")`

`$("#content").children().not(":hidden")`

`$("#content div:visible, #content span:visible")`

Here is an example of html that I would be working with:

```
<div id="content">
    <div>AAA</div>
    <div style="display: none;">BBB</div>
    <div>CCC
        <div>DDD</div>
        <div style="display: none;">EEE</div>
        <div>FFF
            <div style="display: none;">GGG</div>
            <div>HHH</div>
        </div>
        <span>III
            <span style="display: none;">JJJ</span>
            <span>KKK</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;">LLL</div>
    <div>MMM</div>
</div>
```

What I want my selector to select is this:

```
<div id="content">
    <div>AAA</div>
    <div>CCC
        <div>DDD</div>
        <div>FFF
            <div>HHH</div>
        </div>
        <span>III
            <span>KKK</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div>MMM</div>
</div>
```

So, if any element or it's children, or grandchildren, or great grandchildren, etc, contain an element that has `diplay: none`, I want that element(s) excluded from the selection.

Comment: Your HTML needs to be valid first. You cannot nest a div in a span

Comment: ok, fixed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a go with this - filter is also a good idea

```js
var $content = $('<div/>').html($("#content")).clone(1)
$content.find("*").each((_, ele) => {
  if (ele.style.display === "none") $(ele).remove()
})
console.log($content.html())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div>AAA</div>
  <div style="display: none;">BBB</div>
  <div>CCC
    <div>DDD</div>
    <div style="display: none;">EEE</div>
    <div>FFF
      <div style="display: none;">GGG</div>
      <div>HHH</div>
    </div>
    <span>III
            <span style="display: none;">JJJ</span>
    <span>KKK</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div style="display: none;">LLL</div>
  <div>MMM</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about descendants of parent elements having `display: none`?

Comment: How about them? They would not be visible

Answer (score 0):

Here's two ways:

```
if ($('div, span').css('display') !== 'none') {
  // your code here
}
```

or

```
if ($('div, span').is(':visible')) {
  // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#content').find('*').each(function(res,a){
    if($(this).css('display')=='none'){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```